# UIButton extends past edge of UIView with equal widths swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am having a bit of a problem keeping my programatically created UIButton within the confines of a UIView.

The interface is built like;
ScrollView -> ContentView -> (list of programmatically created buttons from SQLite loop)

Here is the code that creates the button;

```
            let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 + (numOfButtons * 58), width: Int(ContentView.frame.width) , height: 50 )
            let button = UIButton(frame: frame)                
            button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=true
            button.layer.cornerRadius=5
            button.setTitle(btnTitle, for: [])
            ContentView.addSubview(button)
            numOfButtons+=1
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

---

This code gives this result;

[Picture of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/473mk.png)

Has anyone got any ideas as to how I can go about fixing this? It seems to me that the ContentView is too wide? but I have it set to Equal Widths to the ScrollView.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Chris.

Comment: You are setting button frame width as ContentView.Width . No, make its width related to Self.View.Frame.Size.Width. Content view Width you might had varied Programmatically for future time saving give button width as related to frame not to content View

Comment: COntentView Width height can be varied but mainFrame width height not so better to set button frame According to View Frame

Comment: @iOSGeek I have tried that and it has given me the same result. My ScrollView is constrained to self.view margins, and I want the buttons to be the same width as the ScrollView and ContentView (Since they are both the same size). Now even though the output shows button width and content view width the same. It still cuts the right side off.

Comment: Example: https://image.ibb.co/btYPAF/Screen_Shot_2017_07_11_at_1_45_00_pm.png

Comment: When are you calling the piece of code that creates the button? In `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @Hodson Yes, is that where should I be putting it?

Comment: It may be that when `viewDidLoad` is called the view sizes are not completely correct. Can you try putting it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead and see if you get the desired result?

Comment: @Hodson Thanks, I tried both of these, and neither changed the result :/

Answer (score 0):

Please check my following code for reference

here is my code output

[image: Output]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var ContentView: UIView!

var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var containerView = UIView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton

    let image = UIImage(named: "image") as UIImage?
    let frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20 - 20, height: 50 )
    button.frame = frame
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=true
    button.layer.cornerRadius=5
    button.clipsToBounds=true
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Hi", for:.normal)

    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000)


    containerView = UIView()


    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    self.view.addSubview(button)


}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    scrollView.frame = view.bounds
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)


}
```